# XML simpleDOM sortedXPath - How to select and display parent attribute?

Tags: php, xml, dom, simpledom

xml file :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<MyName>

<EventGroup Name="Japan Shows" ID="341">
  <Event Name="Sapporo" ID="40163" StartTime="07/07/12 06:00:00" />
  <Event Name="Consadole" ID="5106" StartTime="07/07/12 07:30:00" />
  <Event Name="Albirex" ID="4063" StartTime="07/07/12 05:20:00" />
  <Event Name="Niigata" ID="1144" StartTime="07/07/12 09:00:00" />
</EventGroup>

<EventGroup Name="USA Shows" ID="342">
  <Event Name="Phoenix" ID="40162" StartTime="07/06/12 09:00:00" />
  <Event Name="California" ID="5105" StartTime="07/08/12 08:30:00" />
  <Event Name="Seattle" ID="4062" StartTime="07/08/12 02:20:00" />
  <Event Name="Chicago" ID="1143" StartTime="07/08/12 04:00:00" />
</EventGroup>

</MyName>
```

code :

```
<?php
include 'SimpleDOM.php';
$xml = simpledom_load_file($cache_file);
$count = 0;
$max = 50;

foreach ($xml->sortedXPath("EventGroup/Event", "@StartTime", SORT_ASC) as $EventGroup => $item) {

$time = date("d/m - H:i", strtotime($item['StartTime']));
$event_name = $item['Name'];

    if ($count < $max) {
        echo "$time";
        echo "$event_name";
    }
    $count++;
}
?>
```

Result :

```
07/06 - 09:00 Phoenix
07/07 - 06:00 Sapporo
07/07 - 07:30 Consadole
07/08 - 04:00 Chicago
```

etc...which are all correct.

But what about to show the approciate EventGroup Name? How i can select and display the parent name attribute to each event result? The result i desire should be like this :

```
USA Shows   07/06 - 09:00 Phoenix
Japan Shows 07/07 - 06:00 Sapporo
Japan Shows 07/07 - 07:30 Consadole
USA Shows   07/08 - 04:00 Chicago
```

etc...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the parent of a node with `parentNode()`. Then you can get the attribute value normally:

```
$parent = $item->parentNode();
echo $parent['Name'];
```

Comment: Thank you so much Josh! Worked like a charm.

Comment: I am encountering a different problem now, sorting on @StartTime displaying wrong sorting results, probably cause my feed is on British time (07/08/12 08:30:00 where 07 is the month, should be the day), and instead of sorting the feed by day, its sorted by month. Anyone can help me please?

Comment: What you should do is store the date as a Unix timestamp. It's a number, so it can be sorted right away. Plus there won't be any bugs related to the format of the date, and you won't have to use `strtotime()` either.

Comment: Hmm, searched a lot for this, cant find some solution. Any idea how to start please?

Comment: That's something that must be done when the XML is generated.